# JavaFx как получить Stage из Controller?

Tags: java, javafx

Структура проект такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В App получаю контроллер MainXMLController и через метод setStage() устанавливаю primaryStage.

App.java

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    try{
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/views/main.xml.fxml")); // FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/main.xml.fxml"));
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();

        MainXMLController mainXMLController = fxmlLoader.getController();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        mainXMLController.setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

MainXMLController.java

```
public class MainXMLController extends  BaseController implements Initializable{

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private static double xOffset = 0;
    private static double yOffset = 0;

    @FXML
    private FlowPane titleBar;

    @FXML
    private FlowPane firstKeyboardRow, secondKeyboardRow, thirdKeyboardRow;

    @FXML
    private TextArea typeIt;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        dragUndecoratedWindow();
        setKeyboardThemes();
        setTypeItText();
        installEventHandlerStage();
    }

    public void setTypeItText(){

        typeIt.setText(new DefaultTextModel().getTypeText());
    }

    public void setPrimaryStage(Stage stage){
        primaryStage = stage;
    }

    /* ActionListners  */
    private void println(Object object){
        System.out.println(object);
    }

    private void dragUndecoratedWindow(){

           titleBar.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                xOffset = primaryStage.getX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
                yOffset = primaryStage.getY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();
                println("stageFROM event " + primaryStage.getY() );
            }
        });

        titleBar.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                primaryStage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() + xOffset);
                primaryStage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() + yOffset);
            }
        });
    }

    private void installEventHandlerStage(){
       EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyEventEventHandler = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
           @Override
           public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
               System.out.println(keyEvent.getCode());
           }
       };
        //println("stageFROM event " + primaryStage.getY() );

       primaryStage.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, keyEventEventHandler);
    }
}
```

Главный метод перемещения работает а вот когда хочу установить EventHandler получаю NullPointer? Почему так работает? Или когда программа запускается стейдж не доступен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `public void initialize` вызывается во время прогрузки `fxml` (т.е. во время выполнения `fxmlLoader.load()`), и в этот момент `primaryStage` ещё не прокинут контроллеру.
Варианты решения:

- переместить вызов `installEventHandlerStage` в `setPrimaryStage`;
- вызвать `installEventHandlerStage` самостоятельно после
  `setPrimaryStage`;
- создать конструктор класса `public
  MainXMLController( Stage stage ){...}`, убрать упоминания этого
  класса в `fxml` и самостоятельно установить контроллер

  ```
  FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/views/main.xml.fxml"));
  MainXMLController mainXMLController = new MainXMLController( primaryStage );
  fxmlLoader.setController( mainXMLController );
  Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
  ```
- *тут ещё десяток вариантов, связанных с порядком вызовов*.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @FXML private javafx.scene.control.Button closeButton; 
//или любая другая нода на сцене


 @FXML 
 private void initialize(){

 Stage stage = (Stage) closeButton.getScene().getWindow(); 
 }
```

И не очень понятно зачем вам метод инициализации с ресурс бандлом, если вы его не используете.

Comment: т.е из любой ноды можно получить primaryStage ?

Comment: Да из любой ноды можно получить stage в которой он находится.